# What is a good defensive repertoire against a d4 opening?

Tags: chess-variants

I've been looking for a good response to a d4 opening.  All the repertoires I've studied are against e4?  Any suggestions, thanks

Comment: Need to know a bit more about you. What kind of positions do you enjoy playing? (What do you play against 1. e4?) Also, what is your level in chess? Any of the major openings (Queen's gambit, Slav, King's Indian, Grünfeld, Nimzo, Benoni,....) is good and played at the highest level. For a beginner player, the Queen's gambit/Slav kind of openings are probably easier to play (because moves largely follow general principles) than the Indian defenses.

Comment: I would suggest you use the search function when you will find that this question has been asked before - https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/4588/what-can-i-play-against-1-d4.

Answer (score 1):

The Queen's Gambit Declined. Get "Playing 1.d4 d5 - A Classical Repertoire by Nikolaos Ntirlis"